# Offering free downloads to users as a promotion google play

Tags: android, google-play

I want to offer certain users a free download of my game on the google play store. I need to be able to create a promo code for each user to ensure it is only used once. It seems I am limited to around 500 promo codes a month if I use google play store promo codes https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6321495

Is the only way is to write my own promo code system and put that into the app then offer a way to install the apk for the app and use the promo code to use that app? Essentially with this approach I would be creating an entire new app store which I don't really want to do.

Comment: Actually its 500 per Quarter. I believe its for app reviews/blogs if you are going the paid app route.

Comment: yeh even worse... Is there anyway currently out there to do this?